# Hiberate one-to-one annotaion builds wrong sql query

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have a small problem with hibernate query with one-to-one relation
I created 3 entities. In case of one-to-one relation user-to-group it works properly. I use property `create` in hiberanate config and it creates correct table with correct FK. 
Creating record work correct too

```
MyUser user = new MyUser();
user.setLogin("Mark");
user.setPassword("123456");

MyPresence presence = new MyPresence();
presence.setPresenceId(2);
presence.setUser(user);

session.beginTransaction();
session.save(user);
session.save(presence);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

if get User by presence it works correct

```
int id = 2;
MyPresence myPresence = session.load(MyPresence.class, id);
System.out.println(myPresence);
```

But when I'm try to get presence by user result from database hibernate build wrong sql query

```
int id = 3;
MyUser myUser = session.load(MyUser.class, id);
System.out.println(myUser);
```

Generated Hibernate sql:

```
Hibernate: select myuser0_.id as id1_2_0_, myuser0_.group_id as group_id4_2_0_, myuser0_.login as login2_2_0_, myuser0_.password as password3_2_0_, mypresence1_.id as id1_1_1_, mypresence1_.presence_id as presence2_1_1_, mypresence1_.updated_at as updated_3_1_1_, mypresence1_.user_id as user_id4_1_1_ from users myuser0_ left outer join user_presence mypresence1_ on myuser0_.id=mypresence1_.id where myuser0_.id=?
```

But I expect to see 
`on myuser0_.id=mypresence1_.user_id` instead of `on myuser0_.id=mypresence1_.id`

MyUser.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class MyUser {

    private int id;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private MyGroup group;
    private MyPresence presence;

    public MyUser() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "login")
    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    @Column(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public MyGroup getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(MyGroup group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    public MyPresence getPresence() {
        return presence;
    }

    public void setPresence(MyPresence presence) {
        this.presence = presence;
    }
}
```

MyPresence.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "presence")
public class MyPresence {

    private int id;
    private MyUser user;
    private int presenceId;
    private Date updatedAt;

    public MyPresence() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public MyUser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(MyUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Column(name = "presence_id")
    public int getPresenceId() {
        return presenceId;
    }

    public void setPresenceId(int presenceId) {
        this.presenceId = presenceId;
    }

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
```

Comment: Your mapping is wrong. You have defined two separate unidirectional OneToOne associations. Here's the documentation for OneToOne bidirectional associations: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional

Comment: Great thanks, Solved
Final code
```
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public MyPresence getPresence() {
        return presence;
    }
```

Comment: Hi user3098702, please add the solution you found as answer and accept it to indicate the question is "solved"